# Django "chunked uploads" to Amazon s3

Tags: django, cloudflare, django-storage

We're using the [S3Boto3Storage](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) to upload media files to our s3 storage on Amazon. This works pretty well. Since we're using Cloudflare as a "free" version we're limited to a [maximum of 100MB](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201303340-How-can-I-change-the-client-maximum-upload-size-) per request. This is a big problem. Even the Enterprise plan is limited to 500MB.

Is there a way to use a kind of "chunked uploads" to bypass the 100MB-per-request limit?

model.py

```
   class Media(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
        file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_path)
```

storage.py

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def upload_media(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = MediaSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Amazon recommends multipart uploads for big files. Haven't worked with S3Boto3Storage in a while, but maybe you'll find this gist useful: https://gist.github.com/Hydriz/4413028

It contains an example of multipar uploads of 200mb each.

Answer (score 0):

In order to bypass that limit, you'll have to use something like [resumable.js](http://www.resumablejs.com/) on the client-side to chunk the upload in parts to send to the server via a REST call.  On the sever side, you will then have to reassemble the file on the server side before you push to s3.