# Upload Large files Django Storages to AWS S3

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-s3, jquery-file-upload

I am a new Django, and I have a project that should upload large files (sizes from 5G+).

I am using:

- django-storages
- Amazon S3
- Django 3.0.2
- Python 3.7.6
- JQuery 3.1

In documentation, it says that when the file is larger than 2.5MB, it goes to TemporaryFileUploadHander, which means it goes to /tmp directory first and when the upload is complete, it moves the file to Media Root (which in my case it is the Amazon S3)

Now, the requirement is to stream the upload of file to Amazon S3. 
For example: ***20Gb file should be uploaded in stream (little by little) to Amazon S3.***
How can I implement this requirement to upload the file directly to Amazon S3 directly without having it first in /tmp directory.

Please give me some light.

Comment: where do the files come from? Are they uploaded by users by a web app (such as google drive for example)

Comment: Hi @HoratiuJeflea, the users will upload them via this website made in Django

Comment: Also see this AWS blog about [uploading to S3 directly from web or mobile apps](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/).

Comment: @djvg thanks a ton for this link! letting S3 do the heavy lifting of file uploads should be the preferred solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streaming the file from the web client, to Django and then to S3 is not possible. Best solution is to split the files into chunks from client side JS and then upload them one by one. Sample code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50151682/290036).

This solution will still save the smaller files to disk though.

Comment: Hi sir @Horatiu, I just like to verify this approach, if I would do the chunk in JS client, meaning Django will upload the file in chunk as well to S3? and would not wait the file be completed in /tmp directory before uploading to S3, I am trying to search this but I cannot find an answer. It is confusing because I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53449148/django-chunked-uploads-to-amazon-s3 where it was advised that I need to reassemble the file again before uploading to S3. Thanks for reply.

Comment: You can upload the chunks to s3. Next thing would be to have a job which merges those chunks periodically.

Comment: also check out https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPartCopy.html You can specify the last chunk on every chunk upload

Comment: Hi @horatiu, we have decided to use the multipart upload to S3 using boto3. Thanks